# Resize storage space

Tags: storage

I have Android 7.1-rc2 emulator on VM-Ware virtual box ... kindly I need to increase the space of the internal storage 
already I expand the space from VM-Ware disk settings but still no change on the emulator

I believe there's a missing configuration should be done on the terminal emulator but i'm not aware about it

kindly help 
Regards;